# D3: How to use exit().remove() for Multi-Series Line Chart

Tags: javascript, d3.js

For the Multi-Series Line Chart of d3 (`d3.v4.js`):

https://bl.ocks.org/mbostock/3884955

how has the `exit().remove()` functionality to be applied, if I want to redraw the chart with different input data?

```
function myGraphic(myData) {
    var svg = d3.select("svg"),
        margin = {top: 20, right: 80, bottom: 30, left: 50},
        width = svg.attr("width") - margin.left - margin.right,
        height = svg.attr("height") - margin.top - margin.bottom,
        g = svg.append("g").attr("transform", "translate(" + margin.left + "," + margin.top + ")");


    var x = d3.scaleTime().range([0, width]),
        y = d3.scaleLinear().range([height, 0]),
        z = d3.scaleOrdinal(d3.schemeCategory10);

    var line = d3.line()
        .x(function (d) {
            return x(d.date);
        })
        .y(function (d) {
            return y(d.temperature);
        });

    //noinspection JSUnresolvedVariable
    var data = myData.dataList;

    //noinspection JSUnresolvedVariable
    data.columns = ["date", "value1", myData.referenceName];

    var cities = data.columns.slice(1).map(function (id) {
        return {
            id: id,
            values: data.map(function (d) {
                return {date: d.date, temperature: d[id]};
            })
        };
    });


    x.domain(d3.extent(data, function (d) {
        return d.date;
    }));

    y.domain([
        d3.min(cities, function (c) {
            return d3.min(c.values, function (d) {
                return d.temperature;
            });
        }),
        d3.max(cities, function (c) {
            return d3.max(c.values, function (d) {
                return d.temperature;
            });
        })
    ]);

    z.domain(cities.map(function (c) {
        return c.id;
    }));

    var xAxisScale2 = d3.scaleTime()
        .domain([new Date(2014, 0, 1), new Date(2016, 0, 1, 0)])
        .rangeRound([20, width - 20]);

    var xAxis = d3.axisBottom(x);


    g.append("g")
        .attr("class", "axis axis--x")
        .attr("transform", "translate(0," + height + ")")
        .call(xAxis.ticks(d3.timeYear));

    g.append("g")
        .attr("class", "axis axis--y")
        .call(d3.axisLeft(y))
        .append("text")
        .attr("transform", "rotate(-90)")
        .attr("y", 6)
        .attr("dy", "0.71em")
        .attr("fill", "#000")
        .text("Temperature");


    var city = g.selectAll(".city")
        .data(cities)
        .enter().append("g")
        .attr("class", "city");


    city.append("path")
        .attr("class", "line")
        .attr("d", function (d) {
            return line(d.values);
        })
        .style("stroke", function (d) {
            return z(d.id);
        });

    city.append("text")
        .datum(function (d) {
            return {id: d.id, value: d.values[d.values.length - 1]};
        })
        .attr("transform", function (d) {
            return "translate(" + x(d.value.date) + "," + y(d.value.temperature) + ")";
        })
        .attr("x", 3)
        .attr("dy", "0.35em")
        .style("font", "10px sans-serif")
        .text(function (d) {
            return d.id;
        });

    city.exit().remove();

}
```

***UPDATE:***

I tried to incorporate the proposal [of @Gerardo Furtado](https://stackoverflow.com/a/42729725)  but something seems still to be wrong here:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<style>

    .axis--x path {
        display: none;
    }

    .line {
        fill: none;
        stroke: steelblue;
        stroke-width: 1.5px;
    }

</style>
<button>Click me</button>
<svg width="960" height="500"></svg>
<!--<script src="//d3js.org/d3.v4.min.js"></script>-->
<script src="d3.v4.js"></script>

<!--<script src="v03-exit-funktioniert-3-evolution.js"></script>-->

<script>

    var svg = d3.select("svg"),
        margin = {top: 20, right: 80, bottom: 30, left: 50},
        width = svg.attr("width") - margin.left - margin.right,
        height = svg.attr("height") - margin.top - margin.bottom,
        g = svg.append("g").attr("transform", "translate(" + margin.left + "," + margin.top + ")");

    var parseTime = d3.timeParse("%Y%m%d");

    var x = d3.scaleTime().range([0, width]),
        y = d3.scaleLinear().range([height, 0]),
        z = d3.scaleOrdinal(d3.schemeCategory10);

    var line = d3.line()
        .curve(d3.curveBasis)
        .x(function (d) {
            return x(d.date);
        })
        .y(function (d) {
            return y(d.temperature);
        });

    var data = [
        {"date": "1136156400000", "New York": 63.4, "San Francisco": 62.7, "Austin": 72.2},
        {"date": "1167692400000", "New York": 58.0, "San Francisco": 59.9, "Austin": 67.7},
        {"date": "1199228400000", "New York": 53.3, "San Francisco": 59.1, "Austin": 69.4},
        {"date": "1230850800000", "New York": 55.7, "San Francisco": 58.8, "Austin": 68.0},
        {"date": "1262386800000", "New York": 62.3, "San Francisco": 55.1, "Austin": 71.9}];

    var data2 = [
        {"date": "1136156400000", "New York": 163.4, "San Francisco": 262.7, "Austin": 372.2},
        {"date": "1167692400000", "New York": 158.0, "San Francisco": 259.9, "Austin": 367.7},
        {"date": "1199228400000", "New York": 153.3, "San Francisco": 259.1, "Austin": 369.4},
        {"date": "1230850800000", "New York": 155.7, "San Francisco": 258.8, "Austin": 368.0},
        {"date": "1262386800000", "New York": 162.3, "San Francisco": 255.1, "Austin": 371.9}];


    // d3.tsv("data.tsv", type, function (error, data) {
    //     if (error) throw error;

    data.columns = ["date", "New York", "San Francisco", "Austin"];

    var cities = data.columns.slice(1).map(function (id) {
        return {
            id: id,
            values: data.map(function (d) {
                return {date: d.date, temperature: d[id]};
            })
        };
    });

    x.domain(d3.extent(data, function (d) {
        return d.date;
    }));

    y.domain([
        d3.min(cities, function (c) {
            return d3.min(c.values, function (d) {
                return d.temperature;
            });
        }),
        d3.max(cities, function (c) {
            return d3.max(c.values, function (d) {
                return d.temperature;
            });
        })
    ]);
    g.append("g")
        .attr("class", "axis axis--x")
        .attr("transform", "translate(0," + height + ")")
        .call(d3.axisBottom(x));
    g.append("g")
        .attr("class", "axis axis--y")
        .call(d3.axisLeft(y))
        .append("text")
        .attr("transform", "rotate(-90)")
        .attr("y", 6)
        .attr("dy", "0.71em")
        .attr("fill", "#000")
        .text("Temperature, ºF");
    update();
    d3.select("button").on("click", function () {
        // cities.splice(0, 1);
        data = data2;
        console.log(cities);
//            console.log(JSON.stringify(cities));
        update();
    });

    function update() {
        data.columns = ["date", "New York", "San Francisco", "Austin"];
        cities = data.columns.slice(1).map(function (id) {
            return {
                id: id,
                values: data.map(function (d) {
                    return {date: d.date, temperature: d[id]};
                })
            };
        });


        x.domain(d3.extent(data, function (d) {
            return d.date;
        }));
        y.domain([
            d3.min(cities, function (c) {
                return d3.min(c.values, function (d) {
                    return d.temperature;
                });
            }),
            d3.max(cities, function (c) {
                return d3.max(c.values, function (d) {
                    return d.temperature;
                });
            })
        ]);
        z.domain(cities.map(function (c) {
            return c.id;
        }));
        var city = g.selectAll(".city")
            .data(cities);
        city.exit().remove();
        var cityEnter = city.enter().append("g")
            .attr("class", "city");
        cityEnter.append("path")
            .attr("class", "line")
            .attr("d", function (d) {
                return line(d.values);
            })
            .style("stroke", function (d) {
                return z(d.id);
            });
        cityEnter.append("text")
            .datum(function (d) {
                return {id: d.id, value: d.values[d.values.length - 1]};
            })
            .attr("transform", function (d) {
                return "translate(" + x(d.value.date) + "," + y(d.value.temperature) + ")";
            })
            .attr("x", 3)
            .attr("dy", "0.35em")
            .style("font", "10px sans-serif")
            .text(function (d) {
                return d.id;
            });
    }
    // });

    function type(d, _, columns) {
        d.date = parseTime(d.date);
        for (var i = 1, n = columns.length, c; i < n; ++i) d[c = columns[i]] = +d[c];
        return d;
    }


</script>
```

***UPDATE2:***

There is (hopefully) just one topic open regarding label names and their position:

```
<script src="https://d3js.org/d3.v4.min.js"></script>
<style>
    .axis--x path {
        display: none;
    }

    .line {
        fill: none;
        stroke: steelblue;
        stroke-width: 1.5px;
    }

</style>
<button>Click me</button>
<svg width="960" height="500"></svg>
<!--<script src="//d3js.org/d3.v4.min.js"></script>-->
<script src="d3.v4.js"></script>

<!--<script src="v03-exit-funktioniert-3-evolution.js"></script>-->

<script>
    var svg = d3.select("svg"),
        margin = {
            top: 20,
            right: 80,
            bottom: 30,
            left: 50
        },
        width = svg.attr("width") - margin.left - margin.right,
        height = svg.attr("height") - margin.top - margin.bottom,
        g = svg.append("g").attr("transform", "translate(" + margin.left + "," + margin.top + ")");

    var parseTime = d3.timeParse("%Y%m%d");

    var x = d3.scaleTime().range([0, width]),
        y = d3.scaleLinear().range([height, 0]),
        z = d3.scaleOrdinal(d3.schemeCategory10);

    var line = d3.line()
        .curve(d3.curveBasis)
        .x(function (d) {
            return x(d.date);
        })
        .y(function (d) {
            return y(d.temperature);
        });

    var data = [{
        "date": "1136156400000",
        "Old York": 63.4,
        "San Francisco": 62.7,
        "Austin": 72.2
    }, {
        "date": "1167692400000",
        "Old York": 58.0,
        "San Francisco": 59.9,
        "Austin": 67.7
    }, {
        "date": "1199228400000",
        "Old York": 53.3,
        "San Francisco": 59.1,
        "Austin": 69.4
    }, {
        "date": "1230850800000",
        "Old York": 55.7,
        "San Francisco": 58.8,
        "Austin": 68.0
    }, {
        "date": "1262386800000",
        "Old York": 62.3,
        "San Francisco": 55.1,
        "Austin": 71.9
    }];

    var data2 = [{
        "date": "1136156400000",
        "New York": 263.4,
        "San Francisco": 262.7,
        "Austin": 372.2
    }, {
        "date": "1167692400000",
        "New York": 458.0,
        "San Francisco": 259.9,
        "Austin": -367.7
    }, {
        "date": "1199228400000",
        "New York": 153.3,
        "San Francisco": 259.1,
        "Austin": 369.4
    }, {
        "date": "1230850800000",
        "New York": 155.7,
        "San Francisco": 258.8,
        "Austin": 368.0
    }, {
        "date": "1262386800000",
        "New York": 162.3,
        "San Francisco": 255.1,
        "Austin": 371.9
    }];


    // d3.tsv("data.tsv", type, function (error, data) {
    //     if (error) throw error;

    data.columns = ["date", "Old York", "San Francisco", "Austin"];

    var cities = data.columns.slice(1).map(function (id) {
        return {
            id: id,
            values: data.map(function (d) {
                return {
                    date: d.date,
                    temperature: d[id]
                };
            })
        };
    });

    x.domain(d3.extent(data, function (d) {
        return d.date;
    }));

    y.domain([
        d3.min(cities, function (c) {
            return d3.min(c.values, function (d) {
                return d.temperature;
            });
        }),
        d3.max(cities, function (c) {
            return d3.max(c.values, function (d) {
                return d.temperature;
            });
        })
    ]);
    g.append("g")
        .attr("class", "axis axis--x")
        .attr("transform", "translate(0," + height + ")")
        .call(d3.axisBottom(x));
    g.append("g")
        .attr("class", "axis axis--y")
        .call(d3.axisLeft(y))
        .append("text")
        .attr("transform", "rotate(-90)")
        .attr("y", 6)
        .attr("dy", "0.71em")
        .attr("fill", "#000")
        .text("Temperature, ºF");
    update();
    d3.select("button").on("click", function () {
        // cities.splice(0, 1);
        data = data2;
        data.columns = ["date", "New York", "San Francisco", "Austin"];
        //            console.log(JSON.stringify(cities));
        update();
    });

    function update() {
        cities = data.columns.slice(1).map(function (id) {
            return {
                id: id,
                values: data.map(function (d) {
                    return {
                        date: d.date,
                        temperature: d[id]
                    };
                })
            };
        });


        x.domain(d3.extent(data, function (d) {
            return d.date;
        }));
        y.domain([
            d3.min(cities, function (c) {
                return d3.min(c.values, function (d) {
                    return d.temperature;
                });
            }),
            d3.max(cities, function (c) {
                return d3.max(c.values, function (d) {
                    return d.temperature;
                });
            })
        ]);
        z.domain(cities.map(function (c) {
            return c.id;
        }));
        var city = g.selectAll(".city")
            .data(cities);

        city.exit().remove();

        var cityEnter = city.enter().append("g")
            .attr("class", "city");

        cityEnter.append("path")
            .attr("class", "line")
            .attr("d", function (d) {
                return line(d.values);
            })
            .style("stroke", function (d) {
                return z(d.id);
            });

        cityEnter.append("text")
            .datum(function (d) {
                return {
                    id: d.id,
                    value: d.values[d.values.length - 1]
                };
            })
            .attr("transform", function (d) {
                return "translate(" + x(d.value.date) + "," + y(d.value.temperature) + ")";
            })
            .attr("x", 3)
            .attr("dy", "0.35em")
            .style("font", "10px sans-serif")
            .text(function (d) {
                return d.id;
            });

        city = cityEnter.merge(city);

        city.select("path").attr("d", function (d) {
            return line(d.values);
        });

        svg.select(".axis--y").call(d3.axisLeft(y))
    }
    // });

    function type(d, _, columns) {
        d.date = parseTime(d.date);
        for (var i = 1, n = columns.length, c; i < n; ++i) d[c = columns[i]] = +d[c];
        return d;
    }

</script>
```

***UPDATE3:***
Try for the label (Old York vs. New York) - not working yet...

```
<script src="https://d3js.org/d3.v4.min.js"></script>
<style>
    .axis--x path {
        display: none;
    }

    .line {
        fill: none;
        stroke: steelblue;
        stroke-width: 1.5px;
    }

</style>
<button>Click me</button>
<svg width="960" height="500"></svg>
<!--<script src="d3.v4.js"></script>-->

<script>
    var svg = d3.select("svg"),
        margin = {
            top: 20,
            right: 80,
            bottom: 30,
            left: 50
        },
        width = svg.attr("width") - margin.left - margin.right,
        height = svg.attr("height") - margin.top - margin.bottom,
        g = svg.append("g").attr("transform", "translate(" + margin.left + "," + margin.top + ")");

    var parseTime = d3.timeParse("%Y%m%d");

    var x = d3.scaleTime().range([0, width]),
        y = d3.scaleLinear().range([height, 0]),
        z = d3.scaleOrdinal(d3.schemeCategory10);

    var line = d3.line()
        .curve(d3.curveBasis)
        .x(function (d) {
            return x(d.date);
        })
        .y(function (d) {
            return y(d.temperature);
        });

    var data = [{
        "date": "1136156400000",
        "Old York": 63.4,
        "San Francisco": 62.7,
        "Austin": 72.2
    }, {
        "date": "1167692400000",
        "Old York": 58.0,
        "San Francisco": 59.9,
        "Austin": 67.7
    }, {
        "date": "1199228400000",
        "Old York": 53.3,
        "San Francisco": 59.1,
        "Austin": 69.4
    }, {
        "date": "1230850800000",
        "Old York": 55.7,
        "San Francisco": 58.8,
        "Austin": 68.0
    }, {
        "date": "1262386800000",
        "Old York": 62.3,
        "San Francisco": 55.1,
        "Austin": 71.9
    }];

    var data2 = [{
        "date": "1136156400000",
        "New York": 263.4,
        "San Francisco": 262.7,
        "Austin": 372.2
    }, {
        "date": "1167692400000",
        "New York": 458.0,
        "San Francisco": 259.9,
        "Austin": -367.7
    }, {
        "date": "1199228400000",
        "New York": 153.3,
        "San Francisco": 259.1,
        "Austin": 369.4
    }, {
        "date": "1230850800000",
        "New York": 155.7,
        "San Francisco": 258.8,
        "Austin": 368.0
    }, {
        "date": "1262386800000",
        "New York": 162.3,
        "San Francisco": 255.1,
        "Austin": 371.9
    }];


    // d3.tsv("data.tsv", type, function (error, data) {
    //     if (error) throw error;

    data.columns = ["date", "Old York", "San Francisco", "Austin"];

    var cities = data.columns.slice(1).map(function (id) {
        return {
            id: id,
            values: data.map(function (d) {
                return {
                    date: d.date,
                    temperature: d[id]
                };
            })
        };
    });

    x.domain(d3.extent(data, function (d) {
        return d.date;
    }));

    y.domain([
        d3.min(cities, function (c) {
            return d3.min(c.values, function (d) {
                return d.temperature;
            });
        }),
        d3.max(cities, function (c) {
            return d3.max(c.values, function (d) {
                return d.temperature;
            });
        })
    ]);
    g.append("g")
        .attr("class", "axis axis--x")
        .attr("transform", "translate(0," + height + ")")
        .call(d3.axisBottom(x));
    g.append("g")
        .attr("class", "axis axis--y")
        .call(d3.axisLeft(y))
        .append("text")
        .attr("transform", "rotate(-90)")
        .attr("y", 6)
        .attr("dy", "0.71em")
        .attr("fill", "#000")
        .text("Temperature, ºF");

    update();
    d3.select("button").on("click", function () {
        // cities.splice(0, 1);
        data = data2;
        data.columns = ["date", "New York", "San Francisco", "Austin"];
        //            console.log(JSON.stringify(cities));
        update();
    });

    function update() {
//        data.columns = ["date", "New York", "San Francisco", "Austin"];
        cities = data.columns.slice(1).map(function (id) {
            return {
                id: id,
                values: data.map(function (d) {
                    return {
                        date: d.date,
                        temperature: d[id]
                    };
                })
            };
        });


        x.domain(d3.extent(data, function (d) {
            return d.date;
        }));
        y.domain([
            d3.min(cities, function (c) {
                return d3.min(c.values, function (d) {
                    return d.temperature;
                });
            }),
            d3.max(cities, function (c) {
                return d3.max(c.values, function (d) {
                    return d.temperature;
                });
            })
        ]);
        z.domain(cities.map(function (c) {
            return c.id;
        }));

        var city = g.selectAll(".city")
            .data(cities);

        city.append("text")
            .datum(function (d) {
                return {
                    id: d.id,
                    value: d.values[d.values.length - 1]
                };
            })
            .attr("transform", function (d) {
                return "translate(" + x(d.value.date) + "," + y(d.value.temperature) + ")";
            })
            .attr("x", 3)
            .attr("dy", "0.35em")
            .style("font", "10px sans-serif")
            .text(function (d) {
                return d.id;
            });

        // var text = g.selectAll(".text")
        //     .data(texts);

        city.exit().remove();

        var cityEnter = city.enter().append("g")
            .attr("class", "city");

        cityEnter.append("path")
            .attr("class", "line")
            .attr("d", function (d) {
                return line(d.values);
            })
            .style("stroke", function (d) {
                return z(d.id);
            });


        city = cityEnter.merge(city);

        cityEnter.append("text")
        //        city.append("text")
            .datum(function (d) {
                return {
                    id: d.id,
                    value: d.values[d.values.length - 1]
                };
            })
            .attr("transform", function (d) {
                return "translate(" + x(d.value.date) + "," + y(d.value.temperature) + ")";
            })
            .attr("x", 3)
            .attr("dy", "0.35em")
            .style("font", "10px sans-serif")
            .text(function (d) {
                return d.id;
            });


        city.select("path")
        //            .transition().duration(1000)
            .attr("d", function (d) {
                return line(d.values);
            });

        city.select("text").datum(function (d) {
            return {
                id: d.id,
                value: d.values[d.values.length - 1]
            };
        })
        //            .transition().duration(1000)
            .attr("transform", function (d) {
                return "translate(" + x(d.value.date) + "," + y(d.value.temperature) + ")";
            });

        svg.select(".axis--y")
        //            .transition().duration(1000)
            .call(d3.axisLeft(y));
    }

</script>
```

Comment: Where is your code? Have you tried anything?

Comment: I added the code. So I am unsure where to apply the `exit().remove()` and the `enter()`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Right now you're just adding this line at the end of Bostock's code:

```
city.exit().remove();
```

However, this will not work because his code has just one "enter" selection.

The solution is creating a data-binding selection and a separated "enter" selection. That way, you'll have a working "exit" selection:

```
var city = g.selectAll(".city")
    .data(cities);

city.exit().remove();

var cityEnter = city.enter().append("g")
    .attr("class", "city");

cityEnter.append("path")
    //etc...

cityEnter.append("text")
    //etc..
```

Here is a demo bl.ocks with that change, every time you click the button at the top it removes the first object in the data array, and the exit selection removes the line:

https://bl.ocks.org/anonymous/98204ee0226e2f6178154b7903f9ef99

**EDIT**: In your original question you only asked about the exit selection. Since you are actually asking about the update selection, here is a new demo, updating the lines, the texts and the axis:

```html
<script src="https://d3js.org/d3.v4.min.js"></script>
<style>
  .axis--x path {
    display: none;
  }
  
  .line {
    fill: none;
    stroke: steelblue;
    stroke-width: 1.5px;
  }

</style>
<button>Click me</button>
<svg width="960" height="500"></svg>
<!--<script src="//d3js.org/d3.v4.min.js"></script>-->
<script src="d3.v4.js"></script>

<!--<script src="v03-exit-funktioniert-3-evolution.js"></script>-->

<script>
  var svg = d3.select("svg"),
    margin = {
      top: 20,
      right: 80,
      bottom: 30,
      left: 50
    },
    width = svg.attr("width") - margin.left - margin.right,
    height = svg.attr("height") - margin.top - margin.bottom,
    g = svg.append("g").attr("transform", "translate(" + margin.left + "," + margin.top + ")");

  var parseTime = d3.timeParse("%Y%m%d");

  var x = d3.scaleTime().range([0, width]),
    y = d3.scaleLinear().range([height, 0]),
    z = d3.scaleOrdinal(d3.schemeCategory10);

  var line = d3.line()
    .curve(d3.curveBasis)
    .x(function(d) {
      return x(d.date);
    })
    .y(function(d) {
      return y(d.temperature);
    });

  var data = [{
    "date": "1136156400000",
    "New York": 63.4,
    "San Francisco": 62.7,
    "Austin": 72.2
  }, {
    "date": "1167692400000",
    "New York": 58.0,
    "San Francisco": 59.9,
    "Austin": 67.7
  }, {
    "date": "1199228400000",
    "New York": 53.3,
    "San Francisco": 59.1,
    "Austin": 69.4
  }, {
    "date": "1230850800000",
    "New York": 55.7,
    "San Francisco": 58.8,
    "Austin": 68.0
  }, {
    "date": "1262386800000",
    "New York": 62.3,
    "San Francisco": 55.1,
    "Austin": 71.9
  }];

  var data2 = [{
    "date": "1136156400000",
    "New York": 163.4,
    "San Francisco": 262.7,
    "Austin": 372.2
  }, {
    "date": "1167692400000",
    "New York": 158.0,
    "San Francisco": 259.9,
    "Austin": 367.7
  }, {
    "date": "1199228400000",
    "New York": 153.3,
    "San Francisco": 259.1,
    "Austin": 369.4
  }, {
    "date": "1230850800000",
    "New York": 155.7,
    "San Francisco": 258.8,
    "Austin": 368.0
  }, {
    "date": "1262386800000",
    "New York": 162.3,
    "San Francisco": 255.1,
    "Austin": 371.9
  }];


  // d3.tsv("data.tsv", type, function (error, data) {
  //     if (error) throw error;

  data.columns = ["date", "New York", "San Francisco", "Austin"];

  var cities = data.columns.slice(1).map(function(id) {
    return {
      id: id,
      values: data.map(function(d) {
        return {
          date: d.date,
          temperature: d[id]
        };
      })
    };
  });

  x.domain(d3.extent(data, function(d) {
    return d.date;
  }));

  y.domain([
    d3.min(cities, function(c) {
      return d3.min(c.values, function(d) {
        return d.temperature;
      });
    }),
    d3.max(cities, function(c) {
      return d3.max(c.values, function(d) {
        return d.temperature;
      });
    })
  ]);
  g.append("g")
    .attr("class", "axis axis--x")
    .attr("transform", "translate(0," + height + ")")
    .call(d3.axisBottom(x));
  g.append("g")
    .attr("class", "axis axis--y")
    .call(d3.axisLeft(y))
    .append("text")
    .attr("transform", "rotate(-90)")
    .attr("y", 6)
    .attr("dy", "0.71em")
    .attr("fill", "#000")
    .text("Temperature, ºF");
  update();
  d3.select("button").on("click", function() {
    // cities.splice(0, 1);
    data = data2;
    //            console.log(JSON.stringify(cities));
    update();
  });

  function update() {
    data.columns = ["date", "New York", "San Francisco", "Austin"];
    cities = data.columns.slice(1).map(function(id) {
      return {
        id: id,
        values: data.map(function(d) {
          return {
            date: d.date,
            temperature: d[id]
          };
        })
      };
    });


    x.domain(d3.extent(data, function(d) {
      return d.date;
    }));
    y.domain([
      d3.min(cities, function(c) {
        return d3.min(c.values, function(d) {
          return d.temperature;
        });
      }),
      d3.max(cities, function(c) {
        return d3.max(c.values, function(d) {
          return d.temperature;
        });
      })
    ]);
    z.domain(cities.map(function(c) {
      return c.id;
    }));
    var city = g.selectAll(".city")
      .data(cities);

    city.exit().remove();

    var cityEnter = city.enter().append("g")
      .attr("class", "city");

    cityEnter.append("path")
      .attr("class", "line")
      .attr("d", function(d) {
        return line(d.values);
      })
      .style("stroke", function(d) {
        return z(d.id);
      });

    cityEnter.append("text")
      .datum(function(d) {
        return {
          id: d.id,
          value: d.values[d.values.length - 1]
        };
      })
      .attr("transform", function(d) {
        return "translate(" + x(d.value.date) + "," + y(d.value.temperature) + ")";
      })
      .attr("x", 3)
      .attr("dy", "0.35em")
      .style("font", "10px sans-serif")
      .text(function(d) {
        return d.id;
      });

    city = cityEnter.merge(city);

    city.select("path").transition().duration(1000).attr("d", function(d) {
      return line(d.values);
    });

    city.select("text").datum(function(d) {
        return {
          id: d.id,
          value: d.values[d.values.length - 1]
        };
      }).transition().duration(1000)
      .attr("transform", function(d) {
        return "translate(" + x(d.value.date) + "," + y(d.value.temperature) + ")";
      })

    svg.select(".axis--y").transition().duration(1000).call(d3.axisLeft(y))
  }
  // });

  function type(d, _, columns) {
    d.date = parseTime(d.date);
    for (var i = 1, n = columns.length, c; i < n; ++i) d[c = columns[i]] = +d[c];
    return d;
  }

</script>
```

Comment: Thanks for your input. I tried to incorporate it according to my code, but still I have some difficulties. I put my modified code in the question - it is self-containing now. Do you have any idea, what still is wrong?

Comment: Thanks again Gerardo, that is almost 100% what I need! Just one thing is not yet perfect: the line labels ("Old York" vs. "New York") and their position. I put my code snippet again in the question.

Comment: @JohnnyBigut I know that, I didn't change the labels because I left this task to you: study my code to see what I did with the lines and do the same with the labels. However, if you don't know how to do it, check my snippet again (I updated it, adding some transitions too).

Comment: Hi Gerardo, stll I am struggling with the label - I managed to add the new value of the label (`New York`), but still the old label (`Old York`) is visible (**UPDATE3**). Do you have any idea how to solve this?

Comment: Please, don't keep creating updates, I already answered this question in my first answer. If you have new problems, post *another* question.

Comment: Hi Gerardo, ok, I opened a new question. See: [http://stackoverflow.com/questions/42797393/d3-update-of-chart-via-exit-remove-merge-does-not-process-changed-label-text-pr]

Comment: Thanks for that. If you ask further questions in an already answered question, I'm the only one reading it. However, if you ask another question, *everybody* is gonna read it. Thus, you'll get help faster.